# Can't install Caffe2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, setup.py, caffe2

I am trying to install [Facebook's Detectron](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron) and so I need to install Caffe2. I followed [this instruction](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=ubuntu&configuration=compile).

Basically, I clone the PyTorch repo with
`git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git && cd pytorch`  `git submodule update --init --recursive` 
 and when I run the following command  `python setup.py install`

it goes to 84-86% and I get this error.

```
[ 84%] Built target roi_align_op_gpu_test
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 756, in <module>
    build_deps()
  File "setup.py", line 321, in build_deps
    cmake=cmake)
  File "/home/milos/pytorch/tools/build_pytorch_libs.py", line 63, in build_caffe2
    cmake.build(my_env)
  File "/home/milos/pytorch/tools/setup_helpers/cmake.py", line 330, in build
    self.run(build_args, my_env)
  File "/home/milos/pytorch/tools/setup_helpers/cmake.py", line 143, in run
    check_call(command, cwd=self.build_dir, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--target', 'install', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j', '12']' returned non-zero exit status 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

System info:

> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
> Python 3.6.8 and Python 2.7.15
> OpenCV 3.4.0 for both python versions
> CUDA 10.2 (Nvidia 430.26)

I've managed to get this working before, but can't remember how.